# $\overline{\int}_{E\cup F}f=\overline{\int}_{E}f+\overline{\int}_{F}f$ using ${\overline{\int}_{\Bbb{R}^n}}f=\inf\{\int h|\text{integrable }h\ge f\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Given $E$ and $F$ are disjoint, I have to show  that $\overline{\int}_{E\cup F}f=\overline{\int}_{E}f+\overline{\int}_{F}f$ using ${\overline{\int}_{\Bbb{R}^n}}{f}=\inf\{\int h|\text{integrable }h\ge f\}$.

**I know that** $\overline{\int}_{E\cup F}f\le\overline{\int}_{E}f+\overline{\int}_{F}f$.

Moreover, I have arrived at $\int_{E\cup F}f=\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}f_{E\cup F}$ (where $f_A(x)=x$ for $x\in A$, and $0$ for $x\notin A$).

Now I get: $\overline{\int}_{\Bbb{R}^n} f_F=\overline{\int}_{\Bbb{R}^n} (f_E+f_F-f_E)\le \overline{\int}_{\Bbb{R}^n} (f_E+f_F)+\overline{\int}_{\Bbb{R}^n} (-f_E)$.  I try to use the definition above(with the infimum.) I also try to use $ \overline{\int}-f=-\underline{\int}f$, but it only seems that I am receding. I would appreciate some guidance as for how to use the definition above.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic function on a set is the function which maps points in the set to the number 1 and points not in the set to the number 0. Denote the characteristic function on $E\cup F$ by $\chi_{E\cup F}$. Then, as you indicated, $\int_{E\cup F} f=\int f\chi_{E\cup F}$. Since E and F are disjoint, it follows that $\chi_E\cup F=\chi_E+\chi_F$.

Comment: I stated at first that $E$ and $F$ are disjoint: in the original question the union was written as disjoint-union, for which I know no symbol in MathJax...

Comment: And I also expressed my wish to understand the equality through the definition I was given...

Comment: oops, sorry, I didn't see that you wrote disjoint.

Comment: I will update my answer.

Comment: I still have to go through steps without reasoning. I mean, I, in a way, used this indicator, but whether I am using it or not, $f\cdot 1_E(F)$ are not necessarily integrable, and the same goes for $f_E\f_F$... The inequality is where I struggle.